# Laravel 5.6 session is not persistant after update from 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I updated the Laravel Framework for my App from 5.5 to 5.6 and since then I just can't get the session persistent.

The problem is, I always get the error "Page expired", when making a post request (e.g /login), so it's something about CRFS- Token since I send it correctly with the request I checked my DB where I save the sessions, I recognized that every try a new session is generated.

I tried to set the config/session.php to the original,
delete the browser cache/cookies, 
I checked my Kernel and Middleware if something changed for 5.6,
I cleared view, cache and routes,
and a lot more but without success.

Any Idea what I don't see?

Comment: Try running `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: I tried this already, thanks.

Comment: Which session driver are you using? The default (file)?

Comment: I tested now both, file and database, doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

While I also could not get File or Database to work, it did work for me to switch to Cookies for sessions. Just be careful with how big you let your cookies get.

**EDIT**: So I found out why file sessions were not working for me. My php system doesn't support file locking which prevented the session file from being loaded. In the `/vender/laravel/framework/sr/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php` file, I had to override the `$lock` variable to always be false:

```
/**
 * Get the contents of a file.
 *
 * @param  string  $path
 * @param  bool  $lock
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\FileNotFoundException
 */
public function get($path, $lock = false)
{
    $lock = false; //I ADDED THIS LINE
    if ($this->isFile($path)) {
        return $lock ? $this->sharedGet($path) : file_get_contents($path);
    }

    throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist at path {$path}");
}
```